# Can i update servers via Git?

Tags: git, gitlab

I Have a project on Gitlab 
I Want after **push** commit , other servers update automatically (**pull**) and get new code from project. 
Can i use it? git have hook? If can, how?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- **Make a cronjob to pull  periodically**: This pretty straightforward to implement and will take no time. In your crontab put a code similar to this:

  `* * * * * cd /path/to/your/app && git pull`

---

- **Use [Gitlab Webhooks](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/web_hooks/web_hooks.md)**: This is the most intelligent way to do, but besides activating the webhooks for your repository you will need a consumer app inside your servers that will do the pull when the Webhook informs a push to the repository. Luckily there are some open source apps like https://github.com/miso-belica/gitlab-webhooks that make this job easier.